# Unitialized constant in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the tutorial given [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and I'm stuck at the end of subsection 5.6.

Each time I click `Submit` on the form, I get this error:

```
NameError in PostsController#create
uninitialized constant PostsController::Post
```

5.7 begins with adding

`post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show` to the code. I don't know where to add this or if this would make any difference in the error I'm getting.

What is the fix for this?

EDIT:
Adding 
posts.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :string, :text
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

Comment: Show your `PostsController` source.

Comment: can you post the `app/model/post.rb` and `app/controller/posts_controller.rb` ?

Comment: Added the `posts.rb` and `posts_controller.rb` source code.

Comment: Can you post the exact error from log ?

Comment: You Model-file should be named `post.rb` not `posts.rb`